# QT building project -- static build

Tags: qt

I am new to QT. I have just installed  Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit) which uses mingw compiler. I have few questions.

Please try to answer these :--

I have created a gui application in QT creator. With build configuration **For each QT version one debug & one release** now it created a build folder geny-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MinGW*_Qt_SDK__Debug

Inside this folder three makefiles are there :---

```
  Makefile  
  Makefile.Debug   
  Makefile.Release
```

Inside this folder two folder are there :---

```
debug   ---> contains compiled .exe file  
release ---> empty
```

Q-1> How can I change settings in QT creator to compile my project for the release build ?

Comment: Hi, in StackOverflow, you should ask only 1 question per post. If you have 4 separate questions, make 4 separate posts. I have removed the last 3 questions, but you can still make separate posts to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left toolbar of Qt Creator you will find the button to set the build for your project, set it to release.

With your settings a folder named geny-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-MinGW_Qt_SDK__Release will be created with a *release* subfolder in it, containing your compiled binary.

Anyway, it doesn't have to do with static build, it is simply a release build of your binary, still depending on Qt dynamic libraries. The difference is that the debug build is linked to the debug libraries (for example: Qt5Cored.dll), while the release build is linked to the release libraries (for example: Qt5Core.dll).

Release builds are usually optimized and don't include debug symbols, so they are also smaller.

If you think about static linking Qt to your program (i.e. getting a binary which not depends on Qt dynamic libraries) you should be aware that you should get a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CTRL + T combination.